# client socket send to server in c++

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, client

Hi i'm trying to send a client socket to my server with c++ console app.
I have to say i'm a beginner c++ programmer and i'm fine with c#, when I used this code in c# to connect I saw the response in the server:

```
clientSocket.Connect("the_ip", port);
```

I searched in google to see how its done in c++ but didn't found a simple solution like this. is there any solution in c++ that simple as this?

Comment: C++ doesn't have sockets in the standard library, so no there's no easy way (or rather, no way at all) to do this using only pure C++. You have to either use platform-specific functions, or find a library which handles it for you to make it "easy".

Comment: can you recommend any library for me?

Comment: Asking for tips on libraries are really off-topic here on SO, but I'll make an exception. First, do you already use an existing library or framework, like Boost or Qt? Then read about either [Boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or [Qt Network](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html).

Comment: No i don't..ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

like in the comments were said, there is no easy c++ way to do this but using boost library or how i would do it going for the old c-style.

At [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586000/Networking-and-Socket-programming-tutorial-in-C) site, it is good explained how the socket communication is done. I would recommend you to trie to understand this, because it will give you a deeper knowledge of sockets. If this is to high for you programming skills just go for the boost library.

If you are going for the c-stlye but want to do some c++ just write a wrapper class for sockets, with exception handling and more. Was a nice task which made me learn a lot.

Hope it helped.